# How to reuse properly a Component using Formik?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I am reusing a form to register a new address and update current addresses, when i send values to input by formik it takes a long time (likt 5-6 seconds) I thought it's backend delay but checking status at first second i click on `edit button` to fill the form the backend returns 200m so i think there is a better way to manage this data

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (route.params?.idAddress) {
        setNewAddress(false);
        navigation.setOptions({ title: "Actualizar Dirección" });
        const response = await getExactAddressesApi(
          auth,
          route.params.idAddress
        );
        const data = response.data;
        formik.setFieldValue("id", data.id);
        formik.setFieldValue("title", data.attributes.title);
        formik.setFieldValue("name_lastname", data.attributes.name_lastname);
        formik.setFieldValue("address", data.attributes.address);
        formik.setFieldValue("city", data.attributes.city);
        formik.setFieldValue("district", data.attributes.district);
        formik.setFieldValue("phone", data.attributes.phone);
        formik.setFieldValue("reference", data.attributes.reference);
      }
    })();
  }, [route.params]);

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues(),
    validationSchema: Yup.object(validationSchema()),
    onSubmit: async (formData) => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        if (newAddress) {
          const response = await addAddressApi(auth, formData);
          if (response.error) throw "Error al agregar Dirección";
        } else {
          await updateAddressApi(auth, formData);
        }
        navigation.goBack();
      } catch (error) {
        Toast.show(error, {
          position: Toast.positions.CENTER,
        });
      }
      setLoading(false);
    },
  });
return(
<TextInput
          label="Título"
          style={FormStyle.input}
          theme={FormStyle.themeInput}
          placeholder="Ej: Mi Trabajo"
          onChangeText={(text) => formik.setFieldValue("title", text)}
          value={formik.values.title}
          error={formik.errors.title}
        />
        <TextInput
          label="¿Quién Recibe?"
          style={FormStyle.input}
          theme={FormStyle.themeInput}
          placeholder="Nombre de quien recibe"
          onChangeText={(text) => formik.setFieldValue("name_lastname", text)}
          value={formik.values.name_lastname}
          error={formik.errors.name_lastname}
        />
)
```

I also created an function that return empty values to use it inside formik

```
function initialValues() {
  return {
    title: "",
    name_lastname: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    district: "",
    phone: "",
    reference: "",
  };
}
```

Validatorschema

```
function validationSchema() {
  return {
    title: Yup.string().required(true),
    name_lastname: Yup.string().min(3, true).required(true),
    address: Yup.string().min(5, true).required(true),
    city: Yup.string().required(true),
    district: Yup.string().required(true),
    phone: Yup.string().min(7, true).required(true),
    reference: Yup.string().required(true),
  };
}
```

`getExactAddressesApi`

```
export async function getExactAddressesApi(auth, idAddress) {
  try {
    const url = `${API_URL}/addresses/${idAddress}`;
    const params = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
      },
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, params);
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your validationSchema look like? And is the loading state changed immediately or does that take some time as well? And what triggers the onSubmit? If you could add the total form it might give a better context

Comment: @TimmNL just updated question with validationSchema, my loadingstatus changes inmediatly, also newAddres status who goes to false if its an existing address. onSubmit just update or send new data to backend, my problem is when i enter to this screen, values from formik takes long time to be setted to Input value

Comment: If the response of `getExactAddressesApi` is as fast as you say it is, you could try to use `formik.setValues()`. I would however think that it would not make any difference. If you would set the response of `getExactAddressesApi` in a different state, does that update any quicker?

Comment: Just updated with `getExactAddressesApi` because making a `console.log(response` takes 3 seconds and 3 more seconds to set to Inputs value

Comment: @TimmNL sending to another states they change as fast as i enter to screen

Comment: Could you create a sandbox or jsfiddle that is as slow as you notice right now?